# OpenAFS client configuration

Tags: network

I can't find any detailed guide on how to setup a client OpenAFS on Mac OS X.

I downloaded OpenAFS 1.5.78 from [OpenAFS.org](http://www.openafs.org/release/latest-unstable.html) but I can't make it works.

I read that a panel for the system preferences should be installed, but I don't see anything.

My goal is not configure a server but just to connect to a cell as a client.

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: The tag is wrong, but I couldn't find a more appropriate existing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download http://www.openafs.org/dl/openafs/1.5.78/macos-10.6/OpenAFS-1.5.78-Snowleopard.dmg ?

Upon opening it I was presented with a window with a few options, one of which said "Click icon to install".
[image]

I ran through this installer, entered my password, entered in a false cell name as I do not have a cell to connect to at the moment, and finished the install. 
I do now have a system preferences area called OpenAFS. 
[image: OpenAFS Installer Screen]

It has all of the options though upon first running it does tell me there is an error with a config file not existing, I assume because I would create it and save it. 
[image]

Could you post any error messages from the console when you install OpenAFS? Are you an administrative user? Any other information would be useful in troubleshooting this.

Comment: I finally got exactly what you showed. Very strange... Maybe the first time I clicked on the "debut-extension" icon... Should buy new glasses :p

Comment: And the configuration is OK now. The only problem is it's really slow, and much slower when I go from the finder than using the terminal (ls /afs/cell.name/ ...).

Comment: Honestly the Finder sometimes has issues over network shares. I would check Console.app and see if it is complaining about anything before any big changes, but the Finder does things like index all the files, build thumbnails, spotlight can get involved, and other things that make hobs :(. There are a couple of posts about that around here, some people even use completely alternate file browsers for that reason. Sorry that I cant be of more help!